# Slideshow of images which are not a field of node

Tags: views, nodes, media, javascript

I have used [FlexSlider module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) to create an image slider. It works perfectly. I create a content type, with image field, create several nodes of that type, and finally I create a View of that content type. In the Format of the View, I can choose the FlexSlider style, and I am done.

What I want is to use several large images, which are many (3.000) images, and instead of creating 3.000 nodes, I would like to have the images externally, in a folder and referenced by a table of its own, and do a Flexslider using the View that already have, with mimimum modifications. Is it possible to get the same effect but without using nodes? If I load the images into nodes using Feeds, it takes ages, and I have some problems, so decided to go with the images outside of the nodes. Maybe a SQL alter could do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using [Lightbox2](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2) module, which allows to render a Slideshow with no need of a View or configuring the images as fields of nodes.

You can see the solution with some code, in this other question and answer of mine. So this is a solution for someone looking for:

1. A gallery of many many images.
2. Slideshow with thumbnail.
3. Thumbnail + Medium image (detail of product, for example), with the Slideshow launched from the Medium image, no the thumbnails.

[How to configure a Slideshow with thumbnails in modal window](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182565/how-to-configure-a-slideshow-with-thumbnails-in-modal-window/182643#182643)